# Symfony2 choice_widget print only the label without markup?

Tags: forms, symfony, twig, symfony-forms

Here is `choice_widget` template from Symfony2. I need to print the **label text itself without markup**, that is without calling `form_label` template but simply echoing the text.

The line to be sostituted is `{{ form_label(child) }}`. I've tried `child.label` but it's not working (there is no property label...). Also tried `label` but it prints the label of the whole widget, not the label of the current `child` element.

```
{% block choice_widget %}
{% spaceless %}
    {% if expanded %}
        <div {{ block('widget_container_attributes') }}>
        {% for child in form %}
            {{ form_widget(child) }}
            {{ form_label(child) }} {# here! #}
        {% endfor %}
        </div>
    {% else %}
        {# print <select> element #}
    {% endif %}
{% endspaceless %}
{% endblock choice_widget %}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Form fields' attributes are stored in their ''vars'' property :

```
{{ child.vars.label }}
```